# Android keyboard defaults to capitalized first for html input

Tags: javascript, android, html, web, browser

I'm working on a HTML page. The page is used by multiple platforms: Ios, Android and Desktop. The problem I have is that on the android browser when I select an input the first letter is Capitalized by default. This is frustrating for users as all user names start with small letters. Is there a way to change this default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Android WebView HTML influence keyboard or keyboard features?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304635/can-android-webview-html-influence-keyboard-or-keyboard-features)

Comment: What kind of input are you referring to? Please show an example of HTML code.

Answer (score 6):

```
<input type="text" autocapitalize="none">
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is related to the android Keyboard itself, as mostly keyboards have this option to capitalize the first word by default! In order to overcome this, in your html, you need to force the input to only show lowercase letters and convert all letters to lowercase, you can do it like this:

```
<input type="text" style="text-transform:lowercase;" on keyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toLowerCase();">
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/wuktzx6b/1/)**

Comment: There can be capitalized letters later in the username though so this is not a solution.

Comment: then my first explanation is the answer, its in the user's keyboard's settings.. you can't override that until user decides to turn off autocapitalize first letter