# How can I change the keyboard to numeric for a webview Android?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview, numeric

Tried using -
view?.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('otpValue').type = 'number';",null)

But, only entries changed to number and keyboard didn't

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23462658/13598222) that deals with hooking into the "show the keyboard" event and configuring it.

But you should probably try adding an `inputMode` attribute to the HTML itself, if you haven't done that already. I haven't tried it, but there's a lot of metadata in webpages now to help different things interpret and work with the page, so ideally if you add that info, it should Just Work. [Some info about that here](https://css-tricks.com/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-inputmode/)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question as phrased by OP, and for also suggesting a better way.